# Why do complex roots come in pairs?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

First time using this website so excuse me for using the body like this.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_conjugate_root_theorem

Comment: Welcome to math.SE. Please see [how to ask a question here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: why the downvotes? because granted he can improve the question but it is his first time. His question is not a clear homework question, or even a throw away question. It is a concept he requires.

Comment: Since people will make some efforts answering it is considered to be polite if a question makes some efforts too in providing more details and showing more context that help others to identify the source of the problem. For example, are you talking about polynomials or some other functions? Are coefficients supposed to be real or complex? etc

Comment: *Why do complex roots come in pairs ?* - Because an evil seldom comes alone ?

Comment: The question is unclear. The complex roots of $x-i=0$ do not come in pairs.

Comment: Sorry for the vagueness of my question guys. I hadn't heard of complex coefficients. I'll research my questions more in the future.

Answer (score 3):

Complex roots of polynomials with real coefficients come in conjugate pairs because *otherwise* they wouldn't have real coefficients! Suppose a polynomial $p(z)=a_{0}+a_{1}z+ \ldots + a_{n}z^{n}$ has a complex root $\alpha$. Then $$\overline{p(\alpha)}=\overline{a_{0}+a_{1}\alpha+ \ldots + a_{n}\alpha^{n}}=\bar{a_{0}}+\bar{a_{1}}\bar{\alpha}+ \ldots + \bar{a_{n}}\bar{\alpha}^{n}\\=a_{0}+a_{1}\bar{\alpha}+ \ldots + a_{n}\bar{\alpha}^{n}=\bar{0}=0$$
So $\bar{\alpha}$ is also a root.

Comment: This also works if you have complex coefficients, you know.

Comment: Does it? $P(X)=X-(1+i)$ has only one root, $1+i$, whose conjugate is not a root...

Comment: You have lines over some expressions and certain variables. What do those mean?

Comment: That's complex conjugation

Comment: @Singulis: $\bar{z}$ is the conjugate of $z$ (that's the standard notation): if $z=a+ib$ with $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$, then $\bar{z}=a-ib$.

Answer (score 0):

The key is that *complex conjugation* (i.e the operation $\ z=a+bi\ \mapsto\  a-bi=\bar z\ $ where $a,b\in\Bbb R$) respects addition and multiplication.

So that, whenever $z$ satisfies $a_0+a_1z+a_2z^2+\dots=0$, taking the complex conjugate of both sides, if all coefficients are real $(a_k\in\Bbb R) \implies a_k=\bar{a_k}$, we will have
$$0=\bar 0=\overline{a_0+a_1z+a_2z^2+\dots}=\\
=\bar{a_0}+\bar{a_1}\bar z+\bar{a_2}\bar z^2+\dots=\\
=a_0+a_1\bar z+a_2\bar z^2+\dots$$
i.e. $\bar z$ is another root.

Answer (score -2):

Because, in the complex plane, a root is also a rotation. In general, think of a complex number in polar representation:
$$z=r\cdot e^{i\phi}$$ Then taking the square root gives you:
$$\sqrt{z} = z^{-1/2} = \sqrt r\cdot e^{i\phi/2}$$
But - the angle $(\phi/2+\pi)$ also satisfies the demands for being half the angle $\phi$, because:
$$2\cdot(\phi/2+\pi) = \phi+2\pi = \phi$$

It all stems from the fact that rotations live in on a circle, which is a cyclic space (obviously). When you do arithmetic on angles you must remember that a $full\ rotation = no\ ratation$, and from that it follows that when solving simple equations like $2x=y$ you end up with more than a single solution.